# Override Incoming Email HTML in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird (2.0.0.23), and regularly receive HTML email from people who use HTML background colors. I find them annoying and would like to override the background colors without resorting to viewing all email as plain text. Can I override styles/html in incoming email? I've looked at the available settings under the View menu as well as Tools->Options but they don't seem to be fine-grained enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by creating a [userContent.css](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html) file in your Thunderbird profile directory.